# Anychart/Anystock Technical Indicators

Tags: anychart

I have a line graph of daily stock portfolio prices but we are also wanting to show the percentage of change in the daily price over the time selected. I have found in the [Technical Indicators](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Technical_Indicators/Supported_Technical_Indicators) the [Rate of Change(ROC)](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Technical_Indicators/Rate_of_Change_(ROC)) but it requires a period to be defined and I am wanting the price it compare to is the very first price in the series of data. Is there a way to do this? Thank you for the help in advance.

UPDATE:
So after some looking around in the docs it looks like [comparisonMode("percent")](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Scales#comparison_mode) will do what I want math wise but I have not been able to figure out a way plot the results from it instead of just creating a y axis value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for this purpose AnyStock provides comparison mode. Comparison mode doesn't influence the series shape of the line or whatever. It provides recalculation of value in comparison with the first-price in series, for example (other modes are available). You may find an example below which shows how to use the comparison mode.
Also, you may learn more about comparison mode in [this article](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Scales#comparison_mode)

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    
    var dataTable = anychart.data.table();
    // data comes from the function in https://cdn.anychart.com/csv-data/dji-daily-short.js
    dataTable.addData(get_dji_daily_short_data());

    var firstMapping = dataTable.mapAs({value: 1});

    var chart = anychart.stock();
    chart.padding(10, 10, 10, 50);

    var nonePlot = chart.plot(0);
    nonePlot.line(firstMapping);
    nonePlot.legend().titleFormat(function (){return "comparisonMode='none'"});
    // Set comparison mode to 'none'
    nonePlot.yScale().comparisonMode("none");

    var valuePlot = chart.plot(1);
    var valueSeries = valuePlot.line(firstMapping);
    valuePlot.legend().titleFormat(function (){return "comparisonMode='value'"});
 valuePlot.legend().itemsFormat(function () {
        return "Value: " + anychart.format.number(this.valueChange, 3, ".", "") ;
    });
  valueSeries.tooltip().format(function() {
   return 'Value change: ' + anychart.format.number(this.valueChange, 3, ".", "") ;
  });
    // Set comparison mode 'value'
    valuePlot.yScale().comparisonMode("value");

    var percentPlot = chart.plot(2);
   var percentSeries = percentPlot.line(firstMapping);
    percentPlot.legend().titleFormat(function (){return "comparisonMode='percent'"});
   percentPlot.legend().itemsFormat(function () {
        return "Value: " + this.valuePercentChange + '%';
    });
    percentSeries.tooltip().format(function() {
   return 'Percent change: ' + this.valuePercentChange + '%';
  });
    percentPlot.yAxis().labels().format("{%value}%");
    // Set comparison mode to 'percent'
    percentPlot.yScale().comparisonMode("percent");

    chart.title("Stock: Different Comparison Modes");
    chart.container("container");
    chart.draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/js/anychart-stock.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/csv-data/dji-daily-short.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.1.0/css/anychart-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container"></div>
```